# css grid. позиционирование строк

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Есть контейнер, в нем 9 блоков. Через `display: grid;` спозиционированы на странице в один ряд. При адаптировании мне надо чтобы 4 блока ушли на вторую строку и выровнялись **по центру**. (как будто теперь у нас 2 строки с `display: flex; justify-content: center;`) Как это сделать?

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 12px;
}
.box {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darksalmon;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: почитайте [тут](https://coderoad.ru/46276793/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-CSS)

Comment: спасибо, я понял что это бесполезно. буду делать флексы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по идее гриды этого не делают, либо придётся костылить на гридах, лучше так и сделать:

```
    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
          .container {
             display: flex;
             flex-wrap: wrap;
             justify-content: center;      
 }
}
```